# Python - .join() OR .replace() at the start of a loop with range?

Tags: loops, join, replace, range

*Updated*
Using Python
Question Summarized:
Is it possible to add a .replace() OR .join() in a loop? Attempting to NOT have to add .replace/.join to every print statement???

Input:

```
for a in range(1, 10):
    print("Squirtle",a)
    print("Bulbasaur",a)
    print("Charmander",a)
```

Output:

```
Squirtle 1
Bulbasaur 1
Charmander 1
Squirtle 2
etc.
etc.
etc.
```

**My Goal** is to replace the whitespace " " or join the values without having to join/replace in every print. statement.  **Is that possible?** See below:

```
Squirtle1
Bulbasaur1
Charmander1
Squirtle2
```

Comment: you should tell us which programming language you are using

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is an X-Y problem, where you have given us an example that doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. If this really is it, just do `print(message + " ", number)`

Comment: Apologies nbk.  Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're thinking too complicated or I'm misunderstanding the question. I guess you could just add the two together and get the result you want?

```
for a in range(1, 10):
    a = str(a)
    print("Squirtle" + a)
    print("Bulbasaur" + a)
    print("Charmander" + a)
```

Output:

```
Squirtle1
Bulbasaur1
Charmander1
Squirtle2
Bulbasaur2
Charmander2
etc...
```

Comment: That's it!!  I'm thinking too complicated- operator error at it's finest.  Thank you!